# Laravel JWT and socialite plugin

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am using Laravel's JWT plugin for user login/authentication. This works fine for my users table:[image] when he specifically registers into my website, entering a password, email etc.

In the jwt, i am checking for email(which is unique) and password.

I would like to also implement the Laravel's socialite plugin, to enable login using google/facebook etc, using oauth2 .

Could anybody tell me how to use both ?

I have set an authentication middleware , that checks for the authentication token(generated by JWT plugin). But I am not sure how that will work if I login using g+ etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using JWTAuth https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth , it also supports Socialite login. After Socialite returns an authenticated user, you can lookup the DB by email or create if not exists. Then you can generate token using

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)
```

More discussions can be found at this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-would-one-use-jwt-json-web-tokens-with-laravel-socialite

Comment: great solution, i was also thinking the same

Comment: But What if I want to make an API request with socialite user. I don't have password set for Socialite users in my tables, and JWT ask for email / pass to generate a token.

Comment: `JWTAuth::fromUser($user)` is the other way of generating token. It does not require `username/password` .

Comment: @Thabung is there a similar method for Passport? Generally, how could we do the same with Passport?